# How to set default image to download uploaded doc, pdf, xls files in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image-processing, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave for uploading images(jpg,jpeg) as well as pdf, doc, xls, files in my application.

so when i use

```
<%= link_to (image_tag media.image_url().to_s) %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag media.image_url().to_s %>
```

It shows broken image for (pdf, doc,xls) 
& when i right click on that broken image, It opens save image as box & saves that (doc, pdf, xls) for me.

but all i want is that it should show default image for (pdf,doc,xls) & just clicking on that should open popup of save file.

Using:

1. carrierwave (0.5.7)
2. Rails (3.0.10)

Answer (score 2):

You mean a default image for pdf, doc and xls, **not** a preview?
So you probably want something like:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(preview_or_default_image(media)), media %>
```

and then define a helper:

```
def preview_or_default_image(media)
  case media.type
  when 'jpg', 'jpeg' # , 'png', ...
    media.image_url
  when 'doc', 'docx'
    'path/to/doc/default_image.png'
  when 'xls', 'xlsx'
    'path/to/xls/default_image.png'
  when 'pdf'
    'path/to/pdf/default_image.png'
  end
end
```

Comment: Instead of `media` (not sure where that is being defined above), I used: `model.uploader.file.extension` as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644557/carrierwave-how-to-get-the-file-extension

Comment: Media is the carrierwave object, refer to question above ;)

Answer (score 0):

For more information about CarrierWave, checkout the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads) by Ryan Bates.

Comment: railscasts didn't help me much