# Carrierwave how to get the file extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, carrierwave

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails application that requires file uploading/downloading. For the upload part i used the gem carrierwave since it's very easy to use and flexible. The problem is: once i uploaded the file, i need to know a few things: i.e. if it's a pdf instead of downloading the file i show it inline,and the same goes for an image. How do i get the **file  extension** and how can i do it to **send the file** to a user?? Any feedback is appreciated Thanks!!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Determine file extension (I suppose a name for mounted uploader is 'file'):

```
file = my_model.file.url
extension = my_model.file.file.extension.downcase
```

Then prepare mime and disposition vars:

```
disposition = 'attachment'
mime = MIME::Types.type_for(file).first.content_type

if %w{jpg png jpg gif bmp}.include?(extension) or extension == "pdf"
  disposition = 'inline'
end
```

(add other extensions if you want).

And then send the file:

```
send_file file, :type => mime, :disposition => disposition
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i like the style of your solution, and it worked perfectly. Again, thanks for the reply!!

Comment: where exactly in the rails project files you place the disposition and MIME type vars?

Answer (score 5):

Once you have uploaded a file, the name is stored in the database. This also includes the extension. Assuming you have a `User` model with an uploader mounted as `asset`, then you can get it as:

```
user.asset.file.extension
```

As for sending it to the user, if you call `user.asset_url`, it will give you the URL where the file is uploaded. The user can use that link to get the file. Or am I misunderstanding what you mean by "send the file to a user"?

Comment: Thanks for replying!! well, i want to make the user download the file. You know, donwload dialog (open with.. or keep it or in chrome case keep or reject.)I thought that with a simple send_file with parameters would be okay.

Comment: Well, just link to the file then. You can get the url with `user.asset_url`.

Comment: Yup, i did it! your advise worked perfectly, thanks so much!!

Comment: when in context of an uploader  all you need to call is `file.extension`  e.g. in `def filename; ["original", file.extension].join('.'); end`